# Strange error log results for php pages

Tags: php, error-handling, server-error

I am facing a lots of `404` error in my server logs like this :-

```
[Sun Dec 15 07:48:11 2016] [error] [client xxx.xx.x.xxx] File does not     exist: /server1/user/public_html/x-folder/keyword1, keyword2, keyword3, keyword4, keyword5, keyword6, keyword7.php, referer: hxxp://mysite.com/x-folder/mypage
```

This 404 error only for php pages where I run some php scripts.

Is this attempt try to guess the name of php scripts or any other php error ?

How can I handle this type of error ?

Is this some type of php error ?

Update: There is 404 error for HTML pages also with POST request, insteadof Get, like

```
xxx.xxx.xx.xx - - [11/Dec/2016:08:11:39 -0600] "POST /y-folder//keyword1, keyword2, keyword3, keyword4, keyword5, keyword6 HTTP/1.1" 404 5156 "hxxp://mysite.com/y-folder/mypage2" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: Check the php code and correct your code or `.htaccess` rule. This file, obviously, doesn't exist: `keyword1, keyword2, keyword3, keyword4, keyword5, keyword6, keyword7.php`

Comment: This goes not all time, only some time it error occur, I think it means this is not htaccess problem.